# f:ajax listener with arguments not working with composite component

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, listener

When i try to pass a `f:ajax` inside my composite component all my listener parameters are resolved to null.

```
<c:forEach var="paragraph" items="#{Chapiter.paragraphList}"> 
  <c:forEach var="field" items="#{paragraph.fieldList}"> 
    <util:inputNumber type="double" value="#{field.value}" decimal="2"> 
        <f:ajax listener="#{myean.doSomething(field, paragraph)}"> 
        </f:ajax>
    </util:inputNumber>
  </c:forEach> 
</c:forEach>
```

of course i had added a client behavior to my composite component like this

the listener method is invoked on blur event but my arguments "field" and "paragraph" have always null value.

I think that the variables are not accessible from the composite component.

I have tried to pass the both variables to the composite component via a composite attribute but i dont thik that it is a clean solution.

is there a right way to do this?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<c:forEach>` runs during view build time and therefore the `paragraph` and `field` variables are only available during view build time. They are not available during component tree visit nor during view render time. The ajax action listener method is determined during a JSF component tree visit, not during view build time and hence the parameters will always resolve `null`.

If you replace `<c:forEach>` by `<ui:repeat>` (and ensure that you're using the newest Mojarra version wherein all peculiar `<ui:repeat>` issues are been resolved), and put the bean in the view scope while keeping the getters free of business logic, then it should work fine.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Thank you. i just tested your solution.
At first my listener was not firing but after updating Mojarra version to the latest one it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass arguments as strings you need to write it like this:

```
<f:ajax listener="#{myean.doSomething('arg1', 'arg2')}">
```

Otherwise it will expect `arg1` and `arg2` to be defined variables. I assume that you have your function defined as accepting 2 Strings as parameters.

Also- are you sure that your listener executes? How are you trying to get these values. Please share the code.

Comment: Hello jedrus07,
thank you for your answer
My arguments are not string but complex objects. and their values cannot be hardly coded.
I run my app in debug mode and i am sure that my listener executes but it always get an NullPointerException. when i check my arguments values they are always resolved as null.
I think the problem is that the two variables arg1 and arg2 are not reachable from the composite component. I am wondering if there is a way to pass them as parameter to the composite components without creating new composite-attributes.

Comment: i have resolved this issue by creating a HashMap composite attribute which will contain all my parameters

`<composite:attribute name="params" type="java.util.HashMap" />`

that i way i have always to build a hashMap containing both arguments arg1 and arg2. 

`<util:inputNumber type="double" value="#{field.value}" params="#{myBean.buildParams(arg1,arg2)}">
<f:ajax listener="#{myean.doSomething(arg1, arg2)}">
  </f:ajax>
</util:inputNumber>`

I am not sure that this is the clean way to do it. Can you please tell me if there is another solution

Comment: If arg1 and arg2 are not accessible already, then you need to create them and this make your solution the only way to go (as far as I know). How did you originaly obtain arg1 and arg2 (if at all?)

Comment: Following a sample code:

`<c:forEach var="paragraph" items="#{Chapiter.paragraphList}">
<c:forEach var="field" items="#{paragraph.fieldList}">
<util:inputNumber type="double" value="#{field.value}" decimal="2">
  <f:ajax listener="#{myean.doSomething(field, paragraph)}">
  </f:ajax>
</util:inputNumber>
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>`

My argument actually are field and paragraph and i need to use them while invoking my listener.

Comment: c:forEach causes a lot of headache to people. I suggest to google problems with it and think about building it without using the c:forEach (if possible). Could you also add all this information to your question? You will have much greater chance of a good answer by doing that and then we can delete these comments.